# Reading effect file always returns no technique

Tags: hlsl, windows-api-code-pack

I have a very simple test effect file that I try to load with the following code:

```
using D3D = Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.DirectX.Direct3D10;
...
var DxDevice = CreateDevice(D3D.DriverType.Hardware);
var stream = Application.GetResourceStream(Global.MakePackUri("Resources/Effects/Test.ps"));
var DxEffect = DxDevice.CreateEffectFromCompiledBinary(stream.Stream);
MessageBox.Show(DxEffect.Description.Techniques);
```

The number of techniques in the effect always comes in as zero.

The effect file does nothing but colors the bitmap for easy recognition:

```
sampler2D input1 : register(S0);

float4 DoHorizontal(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR
{
  return float4(1, 0, 1, 1);
}

float4 DoVertical(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR
{
  return float4(1, 1, 0, 1);
}

technique Test
{
  pass P0
  {
    PixelShader = compile ps_4_0 DoHorizontal();
  }
  pass P1
  {
    PixelShader = compile ps_4_0 DoVertical();
  }
}
```

It compiles without any error (using `fxc /T fx_4_0`). Is there any HLSL incompatiblity in Windows API Code Pack that might account for this strange behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your effect still uses old DirectX9 syntax, and you use Shader Model 4, that might create the problem.

Updated version, to fit DX10+ syntax:

```
SamplerState input1 : register(S0);

float4 DoHorizontal(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : SV_Target
{
    return float4(1, 0, 1, 1);
}

float4 DoVertical(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : SV_Target
{
    return float4(1, 1, 0, 1);
}

technique10 Test
{
pass P0
{
    SetPixelShader( CompileShader( ps_4_0, DoHorizontal() ) );
}
pass P1
{
    SetPixelShader( CompileShader( ps_4_0, DoVertical() ) );
}
}
```

Just tried to load it in SlimDX and SharpDX, I get techniques without a problem, so if you still don't have techniques enumerated, this is definitely a problem with Windows API Core Pack.

Comment: By Jove, you're right. Thank you. I wonder why it didn't give an error message then when loading the effect...